# Remote Garage Door Opener

Tags: doors, garage, garage-door-opener

I live in a condo, we have a shared garage but our own automatic garage door openers.  My garage door opens and closes with the button inside the garage hard wired on the wall.  But, my remote opener stopped working.  I just had a new battery put in hoping that was the issue.  It's still not opening the garage door.  Is it possible to get the circuit board inside replaced?

Comment: I would suggest trying to re-pair the remote with the opener before replacing anything; if it's a modern one that automatically learns the code from the opener, it probably forgot it when you replaced the battery.

Comment: Have you talked to your condo association?  Since the garage door is shared, there's certainly an expert who knows all about this door system, and has seen this problem before.

Answer (score 1):

You might not have to replace the door opener circuit. Genie, for instance, sells a [conversion kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RYV05S) that sits inline with your wall panel. The unit has its own radio receiver and works with any Genie compatible remote (which are easy to find). I've used these on some off-brand openers where the remotes died and replacements were impossible to find. They work great.